# Duel boot with window no key board or mouse

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I have partioned my 1Tb drive in half on my Toshiba Satellite laptop, and installed Ubuntu 17.10 on the new partion. The key board and mouse work in Windows but not in Ubuntu 
Im using a blue tooth key board and mouse pad combined , to get round the problem but it's not ideal. What can I do to get the laptop keyboard and mouse to work.

This is not an upgrade but a newly installed OS. 
Very much appreciate your help.